# Sequelize delete rows not present in JSON

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working with Sequelize and Express/Node. I have a model `ProjectImages`, which is a list of the images of each `Project` model. From my API endpoint `/api/projectsimages` I make a `GET` query:

```
// Express router
router.get('/api/projectsimages/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    models.ProjectImages.findAll({
        where: {
            parentId: req.params.id,
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});
```

And in frontend I receive this JSON:

```
{
    "Projects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random",
            "parentId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random",
            "parentId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random",
            "parentId": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Now in frontend I remove the row with `{ id: 2 }` from the array `ProjectImages`:

```
ProjectImages = ProjectImages.filter((item) => {
    return item.id !== 2;
});
```

So now ProjectImages is:

```
{
    "ProjectImages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random",
            "parentId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random",
            "parentId": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Then I send it back to `/api/projectsimages/1` with `PUT`:

```
return fetch('/api/data', {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(ProjectImages),
});
```

Now, my question is: given this JSON I'm sending, how do I tell the Express Router to remove the rows I removed from the array in frontend? I suppose I can make a query in the router to retrieve all items with `{ parentId: 1 }`, compare the result with the JSON I'm sending, and remove those not present in the incoming array. But it doesn't seem very efficient.

Which is the best and proper way to do it?

```
// Express router
router.put('/api/projectImages/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // ???
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, make new end point, verb DELETE. And send to it those id's you removed from the frontend.

Comment: Thanks @VedranMaricevic, but the question is about this endpoint, a `PUT` request and this data.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic I finally followed your advise. And looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you use `DELETE` to remove a `ProjectImage` instead of implicitly deleting database objects from a `PUT` request. After all, what if the front end has a bug and accidentally sends an empty array? This would result in deleted records.

If you are willing to take this risk or for whatever reason, you must perform `DELETE` operations when the client performs a `PUT`, you would have to take the approach you mentioned - fetch the database records and compare them against your payload from the client.

```
router.put('/api/projectImages/:id', async function(req, res, next) {
  const imageIds = req.body.map(x => x.id)

  // fetch images
  const images = await models.ProjectImages.findAll({
    where: {
      parentId: req.params.id,
    }
  })

  const imagesToDelete = images.filter(x => !imageIds.includes(x.id))
  for (image of imagesToDelete) {
    await image.destroy()
  }

  // continue as per usual with your PUT request
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just created a new endpoint for `/delete` items and followed the advice you and @VedranMaricevic gave me: delete each item from frontend with this new endpoint and sequelize `destroy()` method.